# Is my proof that every set in Zariski topology of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, solution-verification, noetherian, zariski-topology

**Proof that every set in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact in the Zariski topology.**

Let $\{ U_\alpha \}$ be a collection of open sets. Let's first pick a numerable collection of them $U_1, U_2, \dots$, so we have something better to index on. We will be done if we can find a finite collection of them such that

$$\bigcup_{r=1}^N U_r = \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty U_r.$$

*(See afterword in the end why I only have $r=1,...,\infty$ here and not all $\alpha$.)*

Now, since $U_r^C$ is closed, there is an ideal $J_r$ such that  $U_r^C = \mathbb{V}(J_r)$. Define $I_j = \sum_{r=1}^j J_r$. Then

$$I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \dots$$

is an ascending chain of ideals, so there must be $N$, such that $I_N=I_{N+1}=\dots$.

But then

$$\bigcup_{r=1}^j U_r = \bigcup_{r=1}^j \mathbb{V}(J_r)^C = \left(\bigcap_{r=1}^j \mathbb{V}(J_r)  \right)^C = \mathbb{V}(I_j)^C$$

and $\mathbb{V}(I_j)^C = \mathbb{V}(I_N)^C$ when $j\geq N$ because $I_j = I_N$. So we get the finite sub cover

$$\bigcup_{r=1}^N U_r = \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty U_r$$

---

I'm little hazy about the picking of numerable cover above. How about if the cover is uncountable? Also, if there are any mistakes in the rest of the proof.

**Afterword:**

OK, I looked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114128/mathbban-with-the-zariski-topology-is-quasi-compact) and it seems one should consider the collection of finite sub covers and then do the above argument for a chain (i.e. a sequence(?)) and so we find a maximal element by Zorn's lemma (or whether you need it or not), now the maximal element is $U:=\bigcup_{\alpha} U_\alpha$, because if there is a set that contains a point that is not in a chain's union, add that set to the chain and you get a bigger union.

Comment: You want to use the fact that $\Bbb A^n$ is a noetherian topological space, being the spectrum of a noetherian ring. This means that the closed sets in $\Bbb A^n$ satisfy the descending chain condition (this corresponds to the ideals cutting them out satisfying the ascending chain condition in the ring of global sections).